# pvlib not correcting series resistance in calcparams_desoto and correcting shunt resistance, inconsistent to reference

Tags: python, pvlib

I am working with `pvlib.singlediode.calcparams_desoto` and I am confused by the following.

In his original [masters thesis](https://minds.wisconsin.edu/bitstream/handle/1793/7602/desoto04.pdf;sequence=1) De Soto proposes equation 4.21 (Page 46) to correct the series resistance for the given irradiation and temperature. However, in the [source](https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/pvlib/pvsystem.html#calcparams_desoto) of calcparams_desoto, the series resistance is not modified, altough irradiation and temperature can have a significant impact on the series resistance (See Figures 4.18 and 4.19, Page 49).

Furthermore, the shunt resistance is corrected for different effective irradiation in the implementation pf pvlib. However, De Soto suggests, that there is no significant impact of irradiation on the shunt resistance (See Equation 4.33, Page 73). After searching the paper for some time, I wasn't able to find another place where this is explained.

What is the reason for those two things being implemented like this?

Thank you very much for your answers!

The page numbers referenced are the actual page numbers of the thesis and not those of the pdf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pvlib implementation is based on the journal paper that was published 2 years after the thesis and the paper has a somewhat simplified model.

```
[1] W. De Soto et al., "Improvement and validation of a model for
       photovoltaic array performance", Solar Energy, vol 80, pp. 78-88,
       2006.
```